# Keras lstm equations, matrices and diagram

Tags: matrices, python

I was reading this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/tutorial-on-lstm-a-computational-perspective-f3417442c2cd), mainly the LSTM equation section for understand the structure diagram and relate it with the matrices and I can deducted this cell diagram:

[image]

I made this homemade diagram because in the [Colah's article](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) it's not the exactly same cell that in keras.

I need know if it ok, can someone confirm me that? This are the equations

[image]

W are weights matrices for input data and U are weights matrices for previous hidden state

b are biases

In the pink circles there are operations. The point it's multiply element by element and X is matrix multiplication

Answer (score 1):

It's ok. The picture and all the formulas in the question describe a standard LSTM network. The part that confuses you may be the content of Keras code: such as dropout and recurrent dropout.

[image: parameter settings] [image: dropout and recurrent_dropout]

As long as you don't set these parameters when calling LSTM cells, you won't be confused about these advanced structures.